What is the correct way to use capitalization and punctuation for this plaque dedication?
This plaque is thanking a small business for their sponsorship. Should the 'w' in "With" be capitalized and is it considered standard to include periods?
Presented to
Company Name
With sincere gratitude for your generous support.
Your sponsorship brought us one step closer to victory.
Team Name
2024
Thank you!


It's a matter of choice, really. Rules do not apply as in an ordinary written text. See what makes sense to you and what looks best aesthetically.

TITLE: This sponsorship award is presented to: name

A marketplace such as Etsy has a lot of examples, but there is wide variation. All capitals seems common, and too many punctuation marks can look ugly; there's a lot of variation in wording. There is a graphic design SE https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ but it typically considers questions with factual answers.

The Trophy House (or whatever you have there) doesn't know?

Please be sure that plaque inscriptions, like headlines, captions, titles and their ilk, are not bound by the rules of ordinary text and if they were, capitalisation would be pretty-much the last thing they cared about.
In ordinary text, the use of capitals follows clear rules.
In headlines, captions, titles, plaques and their ilk there are no clear rules.
Only the author's choice says whether or not every single word should be capitalised… the useful difference being what makes sense to the reader, which should broadly define what makes sense to everyone else.
Does that much work for you?

The current phrasing of the first line is not a complete sentence. Since the second line is a complete sentence, thus warranting punctuation, I'd suggest restructuring the first line into a complete sentence. This will allow you to punctuate both lines, creating continuity and a professional look. You should also capitalize the first letter of each sentence. Finally, I'd suggest switching the order of the two lines because the theme of the second line precedes that of the first. In other words, the sponsorship and victory preceded the presentation of the plaque.
Try this: "Your sponsorship brought us one step closer to victory. We present this plaque with sincere gratitude for your generous support."

But inscriptions of this kind traditionally start with "Presented to..." or similar.
